# Not able to use @Inject in eclipse 4

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to use dependency injection in my eclipse project. I included maven dependency for org.eclipse.e4.core.di in my dependency management pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.e4</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.e4.core.di</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-SDK-4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And also, in the plugin where I am using dependency injection with compile scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.e4</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.e4.core.di</artifactId>
    <version>compile</version>
</dependency>
```

After this, when I try to use the annotation @Inject, I am seeing error and I am not able to see any import suggestion also.

I have tried including the following in the pom also

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What is causing this problem? I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `@Inject` you must include `javax.inject` in the `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package` entries in the `MANIFEST.MF` of your plug-in.

To do this in the MANIFEST.MF editor go to the Dependencies tab and add javax.inject to the Required Plug-ins or Imported Packages section.

When you have done this you should be able to use

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

in your code.

Note: Only classes created from entries in the e4 Application.e4xmi are injected unless you use `ContextInjectionFactory` to create the class.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I included javax.inject dependency in my pom and ran osgi commands, which is same as what you are suggesting here. So, **javax.inject** is not included in any of the plugins I mentioned in the original post?

Comment: No, it is in a separate javax.inject plugin. The various injection annotation classes are spread around in a number of plugins.